# NVML driver/library mismatch after libnvidia update

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, cuda

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and have recently (about a month) installed CUDA 10.2 *with runfile installation* after A LOT of trouble with the [slightly recommended](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#choose-installation-method) *.deb* installation. Everything was fine: nvidia-smi showed GPU stats and I was able to run my parallel code on the GPU. Today I started my machine and the software center suggested some updates...it seemed just ordinary stuff a part from this *libnvidia-compute-440* package, but i didn't pay too much attention and installed the all the updates. After that, my CUDA codes didn't work, I tried `nvidia-smi` and got a

`Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`

I rebooted the systems, still got the errors. I spent the afternoon googling possible solutions, and *I think* I was able to find the core of problem: running `dmesg |tail -4` gives

```
NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 440.59, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.33.01.  Please
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

The version of the `libnvidia-compute-440` package that I have is indeed **440.59** now, but my drivers version is **440.33.01** as `dmesg |grep nvidia` (or similar commands that I've tried) shows (see on third line)

```
 [   16.462737] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
[   16.463235] nvidia 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   16.785628] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms 440.33.01  Tue Nov 12 23:43:11 UTC 2019
[   16.916202] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000300] Loading driver
[   16.916205] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 1
```

In fact, by looking at `/var/log/apt/history.log` I could see that libnvidia-compute-440 was updated from `440.33.01-0ubuntu1` to `440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.133.01`. All these evidence led me to the conclusion that I could try to go back to the previous version of that library, however `apt-get install libnvidia-compute-440=440.33.01` (which I think it's the right syntax) gave me `E: Version '440.33.01' for 'libnvidia-compute-440' was not found`.

I'm really hoping that a solution which doesn't imply *uninstalling CUDA* exists, since installing it took me a weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

I was being very cautious, fearing that I would mess up my CUDA installation. However I took courage and *updated my nvidia driver* with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`. 
It successfully updated the drivers, which now match the libnvidia-compute version **440.59**.

After rebooting everything works fine, just as before.

Comment: how did you figure what was the version of libnvidia-compute?

Comment: @MonaJalal inside `/var/log/apt/history.log` you have the history of the recent updates, I knew it had to be something there and fortunately the only Nvidia-related update concerned libnvidia-compute.